# Erro - HTTP Status 404

Tags: java

Estou com problema para no tomcat o meu site de teste. Quando eu entro ele dá um erro:

> HTTP Status 404 - /liferay/
>
> type Status report
>
> message /liferay/
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.57

Aqui são a parte da msg console, que parece ser um problema:

```
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         7.0.57.0
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 8
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            6.2
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          x86
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0-b132
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf\logging.properties
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\endorsed
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\temp
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;;.
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 600 ms
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
dez 08, 2014 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
dez 08, 2014 11:52:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml has finished in 437 ms
dez 08, 2014 11:52:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application archive C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\liferay.war
dez 08, 2014 11:52:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application archive C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\liferay.war has finished in 156 ms
dez 08, 2014 11:52:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\docs
dez 08, 2014 11:52:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\docs has finished in 94 ms
dez 08, 2014 11:52:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\examples
dez 08, 2014 11:52:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\examples has finished in 344 ms
dez 08, 2014 11:52:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\host-manager
dez 08, 2014 11:52:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\host-manager has finished in 109 ms
dez 08, 2014 11:52:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\manager
dez 08, 2014 11:52:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\manager has finished in 94 ms
dez 08, 2014 11:52:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
dez 08, 2014 11:52:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
dez 08, 2014 11:52:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 1298 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando acessar a raiz da aplicação `lifeway`. Pelo *log*, o `liferay.war` for carregada com sucesso.

Porém, parece haver algo de errado com esse WAR, pois o tempo de inicialização de 156 milissegundos é muito pequeno, menor que dos exemplos.

O mais provável é que o WAR esteja vazio ou que a aplicação não tenha um mapeamento para a URL em questão.

Este é um WAR do conhecido gerenciador de portais Liferay ou é algum projeto seu? Se for do portal, verifique se o WAR não está corrompido ou se baixou a versão correta.

Verifique também se há outros logs específicos, eles podem mostrar erros internos da aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

[Erro 404](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) significa que você está tentando acessar um arquivo/resource no servidor, do qual não existe, por isso, o servidor te retorna um status **404** que seria este tal "Erro 404" para que você saiba que o servidor não conseguiu encontra-lo, verifique qual arquivo estás tentando acessar e corrija o caminho e o nome do arquivo, pois se o arquivo existir, este erro 404 não irá acontecer.